# log4j JMSAppender and ActiveMQ as Camel endpoints

Tags: java, log4j, messaging, activemq-classic, apache-camel

I want to connect a log4j `JMSAppender` to an ActiveMQ queue over Apache Camel, so that both are endpoints along a route. Furthermore, I'd like to have all the config done in Java (not XML).

The log4j javadoc [here](http://logging.apache.org/log4j/1.2/apidocs/org/apache/log4j/net/JMSAppender.html) and [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2097754/using-the-log4j-jmsappender-with-activemq) both show great examples of how to set up such a connection *sans* Camel (via JNDI), but they are not quite what I am looking for.

I know this is possible through the `activemq-camel` Camel component, and in fact that component's [tutorial page](http://camel.apache.org/activemq.html) shows how to set up a pooled connection factory to a broker URL. Unfortunately (for me) its all in XML.

I am struggling with:

- Trying to figure out how to turn their XML examples (link above) into Java code; and
- How to tie everything together so that the `JMSAppender` publishes messages over Camel to the correct queue; this involves endpoint creation and routebuilding

### Here is my best attempt:

Somewhere I will need an `init()`-type method to set up my `CamelContext`:

```
CamelContext context = new DefaultCamelContext();

context.addComponent("log4j-jms-appender", new LogComponent()); // ????
context.addComponent("activemq", 
    activeMQComponent("vm://localhost?broker.persistent=false")); // ???

context.addRoutes(new RouteBuilder() {
    public void configure() {
        from("log4j-jms-appender").to("activemq:queue:log-queue");
    }
});
```

Now, there are already several problems with this code - and I may have even gone down the wrong path entirely. As you can see, I'm struggling to add the endpoint components correctly. I'm also completely unsure of what the string "`vm://`" protocol is or what it stands for. All the other code examples I see involve ActiveMQ utilizing the `tcp` protocol.

Putting it altogether, it would just be nice to write a log4j `Logger` and `Appender` like this:

```
Logger logger = Logger.getLogger("foo.bar");
JMSAppender jmsAppender = configureJMSAppender();

logger.addAppender(jmsAppender);
```

...and then have all of its log messages placed on the ActiveMQ `log-queue` via Camel (and not JNDI/Java).

Thanks in advance for any and all help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The camel-log component doesn't have a consumer...so you can't wire up a route to consume from the log and send to a queue.

One option is to configure a JMSAppender in the log4j.properties as this page describes...

http://activemq.apache.org/how-do-i-use-log4j-jms-appender-with-activemq.html

Also, vm:// stands for [virtual machine transport](http://activemq.apache.org/vm-transport-reference.html)...it allows you to connect to an ActiveMQ broker running in your VM...

Comment: Thanks Boday - so you're saying it doesn't look like I can have Camel be the "middleman" between my log4j JMSAppender and ActiveMQ - I need to just use a pure log-to-AMQ connection?

Comment: its just one option, you don't need Camel for it...just an AMQ broker

Comment: Yeah log4j can send log messages directly to a JMS Broker. You do not need Camel in the middle. However if you run Camel in an OSGi container that uses pax-logging, then you can have Camel listen to the logs using the pax-logging Camel component: http://camel.apache.org/pax-logging.html